# SAS : getting list of numbers based on reducing months

Tags: sas, enterprise-guide

I have this data

```
    data have;
    input cust_id pmt months;
    datalines;
    AA 100 0
    AA 50 1
    AA 200 2
    AA 350 3
    AA 150 4
    AA 700 5
    BB 500 0
    BB 300 1
    BB 1000 2
    BB 800 3
    run;
```

and I'd like to generate an output that looks like this

```
    data want;
    input cust_id pmt months i;
    datalines;
    AA 100 0 0
    AA 50 0 1
    AA 200 0 2
    AA 350 0 3
    AA 150 0 4
    AA 700 0 5
    AA 50 1 0
    AA 200 1 1
    AA 350 1 2
    AA 150 1 3
    AA 700 1 4
    AA 200 2 0
    AA 350 2 1
    AA 150 2 2
    AA 700 2 3
    AA 350 3 0
    AA 150 3 1
    AA 700 3 2
    AA 150 4 0
    AA 700 4 1
    AA 700 5 0
    BB 500 0 0
    BB 300 0 1
    BB 1000 0 2
    BB 800 0 3
    BB 300 1 0
    BB 1000 1 1
    BB 800 1 2
    BB 1000 2 0
    BB 800 2 1
    BB 800 3 0
    run;
```

There are few thousand rows with different `cust_ID` and different `months` length. I tried joining tables but it couldn't get me the sequence of 100 50 200 350 150 700 (for cust_ID AA). I could only replicated 100 if my `months` are 0, 50 if `months` are 1 & so on. I created a `maxval` which is the maximum month value. My code is something like this

```
    data temp1;
    set have;
    do i = 0 to maxval;
    if (months <=maxval) then output;
    end;
```

i thought of creating a uniquekey to join my have data and temp1 data but it could only give me

```
    AA 100 0 0
    AA 50 0 1
    AA 200 0 2
    AA 350 0 3
    AA 150 0 4
    AA 700 0 5
    AA 100 1 0
    AA 50 1 1
    AA 200 1 2
    AA 350 1 3
    AA 150 1 4
    AA 100 2 0
    AA 50 2 1
    AA 200 2 2
    AA 350 2 3
    AA 100 3 0
    AA 50 3 1
    AA 200 3 2
    AA 100 4 0
    AA 50 4 1
    AA 100 5 0
```

Any thoughts or different approach on how to generate my want table? Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Try the following:

```
data want(drop = start_obs limit j);
   retain start_obs 1;

   /* read by cust_id group */
   do until(last.cust_id);
      set have end = last_obs;
      by cust_id;
   end;

   limit = months;

   do j = 0 to limit;
      i = 0;

      do obs_num = start_obs + j to start_obs + limit;
         /* read specific observations using direct access */
         set have point = obs_num;

         months = j;
         output;
         i = i + 1;
      end;
   end;

   /* prepare for next direct access read */
   start_obs = limit + 2;

   if last_obs then
      stop;

run;
```

Answer (score 0):

This problem is a little tricky because you have things going in three directions

- The number of group repetitions descends from group count. Within each repetition:

  - The payments item start index ascends and terminates at group count
  - The months (as I) item start index is 1 and termination descends from group count

**SQL**

One SQL approach is a three-way reflexive join with-in group. The `months` values act as a within group index and must be monotonic by 1 from 0 for this to work.

```
proc sql;
  create table want as 
  select X.cust_id, Z.pmt, X.months, Y.months as i
  from have as X
  join have as Y on X.cust_id = Y.cust_id
  join have as Z on Y.cust_id = Z.cust_id
  where  
    X.months + Y.months = Z.months
  order by
    X.cust_id, X.months, Z.months
  ;
quit;
```

**DATA Step**

A DOW loop is used to count the group size. 2-deep looping crosses the combinations and three `point=` values are computed (finagled) to retrieve the relevant values.

```
data want2;
  if 0 then set have; * prep pdv to match have;

  retain point_end ;

  point_start = sum(point_end,0);

  do group_count = 1 by 1 until (last.cust_id);
    set have(keep=cust_id);
    by cust_id;
  end;

  do index1 = 1 to group_count;

    point1 = point_start + index1;
    set have (keep=months) point = point1;

    do index2 = 0 to group_count - index1 ;

      point2 = point_start + index1 + index2;
      set have (keep=pmt) point=point2;

      point3 = point_start + index2 + 1;
      set have (keep=months rename=months=i) point=point3;

      output;
    end;
  end;

  point_end = point1;

  keep cust_id pmt months i;
run;
```